# Can you disable the 5GHz band on a Wi-Fi card (specifically Intel 6200)?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, drivers

Can you disable the 5GHz band on a Wi-Fi card (specifically Intel 6200)?

I'd like to disable it on the card while I'm doing some testing of our network, rather than disabling the 5GHz on the access points.

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit and driver version 13.5.0.6 for the [Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6200 AGN](http://www.intel.com/products/wireless/adapters/6200/index.htm).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. In Device Manager, right-click on the Intel card and select **Properties**
2. Then click on the **Advanced** tab.
3. You will see an option called **Wireless mode**. Set the mode from 802.11a/b/g to just 802.11b/g.

   - This will prevent the card from scanning or accessing the 5Ghz 802.11a band and just leave you with the 2.4Ghz b/g band to work with.