# Can you disable the 2.4GHz band on a Wi-Fi card?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, drivers

This is a companion question to [Can you disable the 5GHz band on a Wi-Fi card (specifically Intel 6200)?](https://superuser.com/questions/317597/can-you-disable-the-5ghz-band-on-a-wi-fi-card-specifically-intel-6200)

For testing and troubleshooting purposes how to disable the 2.4 GHz band on a Wi-Fi card on Windows?

Answer (score 8):

The procedure is pretty much the same as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/375574/292141). It applies to Intel  drivers (*Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz* specifically in my case), but I assume it is similar for other providers.

First a quick reminder of Wi-Fi standards and bands:

```
| Gen     | Standard | Band            |
| ------- | -------- | --------------- |
| Wi-Fi 1 | 802.11b  | 2.4 GHz         |
| Wi-Fi 2 | 802.11a  | 5 GHz           |
| Wi-Fi 3 | 802.11g  | 2.4 GHz         |
| Wi-Fi 4 | 802.11n  | 2.4 GHz / 5 GHz |
| Wi-Fi 5 | 802.11ac | 5 GHz           |
```

To disable the 2.4 GHz band we need to disable the standards that use it:

1. Device Manager » The wireless card » Properties » Advanced Tab
2. `802.11a/b/g/n Wireless Mode` set to `5GHz 802.11a`
3. `802.11n/ac Wireless Mode` set to `802.11ac`

There is another option `Preferred Band` which you can set to `Prefer 5GHz band`, but I don't know what exactly it does and if it is necessary to change it when all the protocols that use the 2.4 GHz are already disabled.

Comment: For me preferred band alone didn't help, but this did so far.  The options are misleadingly named.  The first option 802.11 a/b/g mode seems to actually control what modes are used on 2.4GHz despite the labels, and since "a" is 5GHz setting this seems to disables all the 2.4GHz modes.